# Gulp Graphicsmagick - setting a background image(composite)

Tags: image-processing, gulp, graphicsmagick

How can I add a background image to a partially transparent png using Graphicsmagick Gulp module? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gm)

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task("addBackground", function () {
  gulp.src('input/*.png')
  .pipe(gm(function (gmfile) {
    return gmfile.composite('background.jpg');
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('output/'));
});
```

However when I try to run this my tasks all finish and then it throws the following error:
[image]

Any insight on how to fix this or what is going on here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same error and finally found a solution; it may not work for what you are planning since you're trying to add a background, but it does result in a solution to combine 2 images.  Hopefully, this can give you a starting point to find a better solution.

```
gulp.task( 'composite', function () {
   gulp.src('path/image.png')

   .pipe( gm( function ( gmfile ) {
       return gmfile
       .draw('image Over 2,2 0,0 path/overlay.png')
   } ) )
   .pipe( gulp.dest( 'newpath/' ) );
} );
```

The first set of numbers "2,2" are for the x,y start. I'm not sure what the second set does yet.

I found the solution based on this github disscusion about watermarks: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/276